# Unable to symbolicate frameworks sometimes

Tags: ipad, xcode4.2, symbolicate

I am completely at a loss on this one. I was able to symbolicate one of my crash reports (obtained from a user submitting it via the app) and it looked like this:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x360a3fbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x360a50c5 _objc_rootRelease + 37
2   Foundation                          0x31b7ec75 _timerRelease + 49
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3729e709 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 429
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3729d29f __CFRunLoopRun + 1207
5   CoreFoundation                      0x372204dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
6   CoreFoundation                      0x372203a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
7   GraphicsServices                    0x35dddfed GSEventRunModal + 157
8   UIKit                               0x3055b743 UIApplicationMain + 1091
9   [App Name]                          0x00002463 main (main.m:54)
```

However all of the rest of the crash reports look like this after being symbolicated:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3790bfbc 0x37908000 + 16316
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3790d0c5 0x37908000 + 20677
2   Foundation                          0x3505ec75 0x3505a000 + 19573
3   CoreFoundation                      0x37d99709 0x37d0c000 + 579337
4   CoreFoundation                      0x37d9829f 0x37d0c000 + 574111
5   CoreFoundation                      0x37d1b4dd 0x37d0c000 + 62685
6   CoreFoundation                      0x37d1b3a5 0x37d0c000 + 62373
7   GraphicsServices                    0x37af2fcd 0x37aef000 + 16333
8   UIKit                               0x3189b743 0x3186a000 + 202563
9   [App Name]                          0x00002463 main (main.m:54)
```

Why do CoreFoundation, UIKit, etc. symbolicate in the first instance but not for the rest?

NOTE: I do have the original archive (that was submitted to the app store) and these are being symbolicated within Xcode 4.2 simply by dragging it into the organizer.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not have the symbols on your Mac of the iOS version that crashed.

Check the iOS Version of the crash report (shows up in the top part of the report) and then check if you have the symbols for this iOS version here: `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this still is a requirement for 5.1.1 crash logs.  Looking at the folder, I only have up to iOS 4.3.5, but I've been using new devices and Xcode 4.3.2.

Comment: They are now part of the application package. You'll find them in `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`